# My app does not create new files unless restarted

Tags: java, android

The app records audio. Each time a check is performed so if a file is about to be created it does not replace the previous file with the same name, but creates a new one adding "(number)" to their name instead.

This is the code for it:

```
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    int entryNumber = 1;
    File mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording (" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ")" + ".mp3");
    while (mFile.exists()) {
        entryNumber++;
        mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording (" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ")" + ".mp3");
    }
    this.mFileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Recording process:

```
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                    try {
                        mRecorder.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                    }
                    mRecorder.start();
                    isRecording = true;
                    recordBtn.setText("Stop");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I noticed a bug. The app does create new files only if it **exits and starts again**.

Should the user continue recording sound, the app will not create a new file but instead will write over the previous file replacing it. It is supposed to always create a new file appon recording.

FULL PROJECT CODE HERE:

```
package com.android.greg.garec;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button recordBtn, playBtn;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String mFileName = null;
    public static final int REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    boolean isRecording = false;
    boolean isPlaying = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recordBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        playBtn.setEnabled(false);
        playBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        int entryNumber = 1;
        File mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".mp3");
        while (mFile.exists()) {
            // File exists, just increment number
            entryNumber++;
        }

        // Only create the file when it does not exist
        mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".mp3");
        try {
            mFile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.mFileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //Record button actions
        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isRecording) {
                    playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    isRecording = false;
                    recordBtn.setText("Record");
                } else {
                    if (CheckPermissions()) {
                        playBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        playBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                        try {
                            mRecorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                        }
                        mRecorder.start();
                        isRecording = true;
                        recordBtn.setText("Stop");
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        RequestPermissions();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //Play button actions
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isPlaying) {
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = null;
                    recordBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    isPlaying=false;
                    playBtn.setText("Play");
                } else {
                    recordBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                        mPlayer.start();
                   //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recorded playback started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                isPlaying = false;
                          //      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recorded playback finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                                playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                playBtn.setText("Play");
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                    }
                    isPlaying=true;
                    playBtn.setText("Stop");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Permission checks - requests
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean permissionToStore = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean permissionToRead = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (permissionToRecord && permissionToStore && permissionToRead) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermissions () {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void RequestPermissions () {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{RECORD_AUDIO, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:text="Record" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: new File(..) doesn't make a file on your drive, it makes on in memory

Comment: To understand why this bug happens, we need to look at where this code is called from. In particular - where do you actually write into a file and whether you actually call the code to create a new file when you start recording.

Comment: Question edited to show recording process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new File()` just create a new object, not an actual File on the file system.

Use `createNewFile()` to create an empty file ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#createNewFile())):

```
File file = new File(mFileName + "/Recording (" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ")" + ".mp3");
if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Example that should work without replaceing existing files :

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    int entryNumber = 1;
    File mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording (" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ")" + ".mp3");
    while (mFile.exists()) {
        // File exists, just increment number
        entryNumber++;
    }
    // Only create the file when it does not exists
    mFile = new File(mFileName + "/Recording (" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ")" + ".mp3");
    try {
        mFile.createNewFile()
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStacjTrace();
    }
    this.mFileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mind editing for some more in depth details? how would you reform my code?

Comment: What don't you understand ? The documentation of `createNewFile()` is quite clear. It creates a new empty file on the file system. That's it. Furthermore, I think your code will not work and rewrite over existing files. I posted an example that should work on my post.

Comment: I replaced my file code with yours. Even though your code appears reasonable (minus some typos that i fixed), the app does not show the buttons on launch so i cannot test it. When i revert back to the original code the problem is not present. I don't know what may be causing this.

Comment: If i change the file name, for example i set the file name as "Recording1", then it will work. If i close the app and open again then buttons are not shown.

Comment: A good practice for file names is to avoid space and special charaters except for "_". You should try to write files with a names like "Record_1.mp3"

Comment: And I don't understand which buttons you aretalking about.

Comment: The app buttons, as in RECORD, STOP etc in the UI of the app. It works normally. Then i close the app and start over. The app starts and the buttons are missing. Crazy right? i know... Pure madness.

Comment: Well, if there was a way to pm you i would have sent you the entire code to build it on your own and test.

Comment: You can edit your code and share a link to retrieve the code

Comment: I edited the question, added the entire java and xml files and the permissions needed for the manifest. You can build it on the spot by copy-pasting.

Comment: In ` playBtn.setOnClickListener` I think you missed to add `recordBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
According to which button you want to display when you are playing sound, you should review this part of code.

Comment: This is not it man. No matter what you do with visibility when the code looks like this it will not get to show any buttons. Try it out yourself and you ll see. Anyway, i'm gonna give you the tick because i can tell that you tried.

Comment: I'll try tonight :)

Comment: Well, if you happen to find out anything give me a hint at least ^^

Comment: The app will show its buttons using the code you provided as long as you put a *break;* in the while loop after the increment. If you remove the break then the buttons don't show! I have never seen anything like it. Unreal...

Comment: I can't test it right now but I have an idea. If you have many files to check, it's possible that the loop blocks the UI Thread. May be you should try to run this loop outside the UIThread. Check here : https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93

Comment: I tried and the record button shows up as well as the play button.

Comment: And works as intended? Creating new audio files incrementally?

Comment: It seemed to work but now it's not... I'll try later to found a solution